# Firebase query not returning any data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My datamodel looks as follows :

```
allcomments
|__$comment_id_5
         |__post_id: <post_id_5>



uid
|
|__activity
     |__comments
            |__$random_activity_id
                       |__post_id : <post_id_5> //ref to post_id_5 in allcomments
                       |__comment_id : <comment_id_5> // ref to comment_id_5 in allcomments
```

**My Goal**: To check if the user with `uid` has commented on the post or not. If that person has, then I he can proceed further else he'll be shown something else on the screen. On trying the following query, I am able to only get the callback when a snapshot exists and not otherwise.

```
FBDataservice.ds.child("allcomments").queryOrdered(byChild: "post_id").queryEqual(toValue: "post_id_5").observeSingleEvent(of: .ChildAdded) { (snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.value as? DataDict {
            let comment = Comment(comId: snapshot.key , comData: data)
            self.checkUserHasResponded(completion: { (hasResponded) in
                if !hasResponded {
                    // Never returns it there is nothng
                    print("You gotta respond first")
                } else {
                    //this part does work
                    print("Welcome to seeing everything")
                }
            })
        }
    }


func checkUserHasResponded(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    FBDataservice.ds.REF_USERS.child(uid).child("activity/comments").queryOrdered(byChild: "post_id").queryEqual(toValue: "post_id_5").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        snapshot.exists() ? completion(true) : completion(false)
    }
}
```

I even tried tweaking the architecture this way and query it differently, still nothing work and the program behaves in the same exact way as incase of above.

```
uid
|
|__activity
     |__comments
            |__post_id_5 : comment_id_5
```

and ran this query:

```
func checkUserHasResponded(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    FBDataservice.ds.REF_USERS.child(uid).child("activity/comments").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        snapshot.hasChild("post_id_5") ? completion(true) : completion(false)
    }
}
```

I tried changing `.childAdded` to `.value`. It gives the same exact result. Tried changing `.observeSingleEvent(of:)` to `.observe()` as well. But nothing helps. I am not sure what exactly is wrong. Check plenty of answers here, none helped. What exactly am I over looking. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you get if you print `snapshot.exists()` for true and false cases? also, a bit unrelated but latest swift syntax is `@escaping (Bool) -> Void`

Comment: Well, it prints nothing of `!snapshot.exists()`. Else it does. Also, yup I am aware. I just wrote that in the good old fashion way + the habbits :)

Comment: Well. That's not going to display anything as the node name is *allcomments* and you're code is trying to access *allcommets*  (it's missing an 'n')

Comment: @Jay Sorry Its a typo while editing. But even if it has an "n". It doesnt work :(

Comment: Is the goal here to determine if a user has responded to a post?

Comment: @Jay yup, thats right. And then even display the comments assosiated with that specific post. Hence all the querying

Comment: The structure appears a little weird; within activity/comments you've got a child node of the comment_id. But then within that node, the is another comment_id child with a commendID value. Not sure what the purpose of that is and it seems the structure could be simplified to allow easier access. Also, the completion handlers really aren't necessary and may be causing more issues. I would suggest asking another question with additional information about how your structure is being used.

Comment: @Jay well, consider that $`comment_id` under activity/comments as `$activity_id`. But let me try out another way. If that doesnt work, I'll post a question and update you here. Thanks alot for the help mate. Cheers

Comment: @Jay Hey I tried, but still have some issues. I have put a clear explanation in the question and rephrased it from scratch, Please have a look and let me know if you find any error

Comment: Ok. Updated the answer to address both the original question as well as the updated one. Be sure to accept it again if it helps.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the help mate. I ended up using something else, but this clearly worked. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use .value instead of .childAdded, that way it the closure is called whether or not the snapshot exists, Just a quick test shows it works.

```
func checkUserHasResponded() {
    let uid = "uid_0"
    let commentsRef = dbRef.child(uid).child("activity").child("comments")
    commentsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "post_id")
               .queryEqual(toValue: "post_5")
               .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            print("post exists")
        } else {
            print("post not found")
        }
    }
}
```

If your structure does not contain a post_id child value that exists then the output is

```
post not found
```

So this answer applies to the updated question. The code in the closure will not run if the node you're querying for does not exist because the query is using .childAdded

```
FBDataservice.ds.child("allcomments").queryOrdered(byChild: "post_id")
                                 .queryEqual(toValue: "post_id_5")
                                 .observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded) { (snapshot) in
```

If that's changed to .value, it returns and the code in the closure runs if the node exists. Keeping in mind that you'll want to use

```
snapshot.exists()
```

with that as it will be nil if it doesn't.

Comment: Damn! I did tried that. But for some reason it didnt work last night. I even mentioned in the question. It just worked. But the issue now is if this closure is called inside of another `Firebase Query` closure, everything goes back to square one.

Comment: @AakashDave Glad it helped! Not sure what the use case would be if you needed to call this inside another query. Perhaps posting another question providing some details would help?

Comment: @AakashDave Since this answer specifically answers the existing question. Your comment sounds like it's a bit of a different question which may have a different answer.

Comment: Updated the question. Well, the question is quite apt for what I want I am asking. I just posted a tiny chunk of code that didnt work, but it gives me the same erroneous behavior when implemented this way. If I call this closure as a stand alone method it works, but never does in the close.

Comment: I have posted a question here about a firebase issue, I think I can use your help here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324976/firebase-app-crashed-on-launch-when-made-active-from-backgrund

Comment: Can you help me out here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339775/implement-twitter-profile-like-view-with-parallax-scroll